# Cloudfront serving png/jpg vs webp based on request headers

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, webp

I have Cloudfront in front of S3 serving images (png and jpg).
I have all png and jpg images in webp format in the same directory with .webp extension. For example:

- png: /path/to/file.png
- webp: /path/to/file.png.webp

I'd like to serve the webp file dynamically without changing the markup.
Since browsers flag webp support via Accept header, what i need to do is: if the user has support for webp (via Accept header) Cloudfront would pull the webp version (filename.png.webp), if not it should serve the original file (filename.png)

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Making Cloudfront serve different resources is easy (when you have done it a couple of times), but my concern is whether the entity making the request (i.e. browser) and possible caching elements between (proxies etc) expects to have different media types on the same request URI. But that is a bit beyond your question. I believe the [usual way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) to handle this problem is with a  element where the browser is free to choose an image from different media types like this:

```
<picture>
  <source type="image/svg+xml" srcset="pyramid.svg" />
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="pyramid.webp" />
  <img
    src="pyramid.png"
    alt="regular pyramid built from four equilateral triangles" />
</picture>
```

But if you still want to serve different content from Cloufront for the same URL this is how you do it:

Cloudfront has 4 different points where you can inject a lamdba function for request manipulation (Lambda@Edge).

[image: Lambda@Edge]

For your use case we need to create a Lambda@Edge function at the Origin Request location then associate this function with your Cloudfront Distribution.

Below is an example from [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html) that looks on device type and does URL manipulation. For your use case, something similar can be done by looking at the "Accept" header.

```
'use strict';

/* This is an origin request function */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;

    /*
     * Serve different versions of an object based on the device type.
     * NOTE: 1. You must configure your distribution to cache based on the
     *          CloudFront-Is-*-Viewer headers. For more information, see
     *          the following documentation:
     *          https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/cloudfront/cache-on-selected-headers
     *          https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/cloudfront/cache-on-device-type
     *       2. CloudFront adds the CloudFront-Is-*-Viewer headers after the viewer
     *          request event. To use this example, you must create a trigger for the
     *          origin request event.
     */

    const desktopPath = '/desktop';
    const mobilePath = '/mobile';
    const tabletPath = '/tablet';
    const smarttvPath = '/smarttv';

    if (headers['cloudfront-is-desktop-viewer']
        && headers['cloudfront-is-desktop-viewer'][0].value === 'true') {
        request.uri = desktopPath + request.uri;
    } else if (headers['cloudfront-is-mobile-viewer']
               && headers['cloudfront-is-mobile-viewer'][0].value === 'true') {
        request.uri = mobilePath + request.uri;
    } else if (headers['cloudfront-is-tablet-viewer']
               && headers['cloudfront-is-tablet-viewer'][0].value === 'true') {
        request.uri = tabletPath + request.uri;
    } else if (headers['cloudfront-is-smarttv-viewer']
               && headers['cloudfront-is-smarttv-viewer'][0].value === 'true') {
        request.uri = smarttvPath + request.uri;
    }
    console.log(`Request uri set to "${request.uri}"`);

    callback(null, request);
};
```

Next you need to tell Cloudfront that you want to use the Accept header as a part of your cache key (otherwise Cloudfront would only execute your Origin Request lambda once and also not expose this header to your function).
You do this nowadays with cache and origin request policies. Or with legacy settings (Edit Behaviour under your Cloudfront distribution settings) such as:
[image]

Worth to note here is that, if you get low cache hit ratio due to different variants of the Accept header you need to pre-process / clean it. The way I would do it is with a Viewer Request Lamdba that gets executed for each request. This new Lambda would then check if the Accept header supports Webp and then add a single NEW header to the request that it passes on to the Origin Request above. That way the Origin Request can cache on this new header (which only has two different possible values)

There's more config/setup needed such as IAM policies to get Lamdba to run etc, but there's lots of great material out there that walks you through the steps. [Maybe start here?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-how-it-works-tutorial.html)